# Xamarin Android create and write to a file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I have VS2017 and have my device (Samsung note4 ) connected
 tested and it works. But I want to create and write to a file

```
 string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filename = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
```

I run this on the device and no error or anything. debugger is not  throwing any error. but when I search for this file on  my phone, I can't find it any where at all. did it create a file, and wrote to it? if so, where would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, try to read it to make sure where it is; This is how you can do it, for more details [please see the xamarin forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/18998/#Comment_18998), hope it helps;

```
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        string filename = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
        }

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nurhak,   I see the content and location. the location is: /data/user/0/App5.andriod/files/myfile.txt.   but how can I browse to it from the device or my PC?

Comment: As your question has been answered, can you please mark my answer as the answer to your question? Coming to your other question: Now you have the streamReader content data which comes from your txt file. Just show it on the mobile app by binding it with a textview. Here are some options and some examples how you can do it. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/ https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2921/displaying-string-on-a-textview

Comment: To be more specific; you can use label for presenting single or multi-line text. It will show text with multiple formatting options in the same line. Here is some more details about it: Hope it helps. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label/#Color

Comment: Well, my question has not been answered yet.  How can I browse to the file I created from my android device? looked everywhere and could not find the file